# VBA's Worksheet_Change function using the Intersect method with Cells as the Range definer

Tags: vba, excel, intersect

I am trying to make my spreadsheet autofill the corresponding cell when one of the related cells have been changed.
I have previous just defined the target as:

```
 If Target.Address = "$A$5" then
```

and had no issues.
However, now my target can be one of many cells and I read that the intersect method should be able to work for this but when I input my code as:

```
If Intersect(Target, Range(Cells(12,2), Cells(12,j-1))) Is Nothing Then
```

(I am trying to change the cells below the target, with the target being any of the cells between 12B and 12(j-1) with j being previously defined)
I get the following error:
"Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error"
But from I can tell, my code is exactly the same as all the examples around.

My full code is (although there may be an unrelated error with my vlookup as well)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Intersect(Target, Range(Cells(12, 2), Cells(12, j-1))) Is Nothing Then
    If IsEmpty(Target) Then
        Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 19
    Else:
        If Range("$A$13").Value = "" Then
            Range("$A$13").Value = "Care Type"
            Range("$A$13").Font.Bold = True
        End If
        Target.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
        Target.Offset(1, 0).Interior.ColorIndex = 19
        Target.Offset(2, 0).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction. _
            VLookup(Target, Sheets("Sheet2").Range("$E$3:$F$6"), 2)
        Target.Offset(2, 0).Font.Bold = True

        i = 2
        Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(11, i))
            If Cells(11, i).Value <= ChildCount Then
                Cells(12, i).Interior.ColorIndex = 19
            End If
        i = i + 1
        Loop
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Always helps to post your actual code.

Comment: If **NOT** Intersect( ... ) Is Nothing Then

Comment: thanks, I've added the rest of my code and I've also tried using the If Not Intersect but got the same error

Comment: At Cells(12,j-1),  if j is 1 code occur error.

Comment: Where is `j` defined?  You say it is, but it must be done in a different block of code...  Can you use `Debug.Print` to check that it hasn't been reset back to 1 or 0 or something silly like that.

Comment: yes, I think you are right, the error must be with the j. What I am trying to do is create a form that auto populates. j would be defined in the previous question that asks the number of dogs you have. if you have 5 dogs, then j=6, if you have 1 then j=2. This would explain why the error only really pops up when I try to start from scratch

Answer (score 1):

After using Intersect to determine that at least one cell in your range has been changed, you need to iterate through the matching cells.

Turn off event handling or the Worksheet_Change will run on top of itself when you start changing values on the worksheet.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If not Intersect(Target, Range(Cells(12, 2), Cells(12, 11))) Is Nothing Then
        on error goto safe_exit
        application.enableevents = false
        dim t as range
        for each t in Intersect(Target, Range(Cells(12, 2), Cells(12, 11)))
            If IsEmpty(t) Then
                t.Interior.ColorIndex = 19
            Else
                If Range("$A$13").Value = "" Then
                    Range("$A$13").Value = "Care Type"
                    Range("$A$13").Font.Bold = True
                End If
                t.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
                t.Offset(1, 0).Interior.ColorIndex = 19
                t.Offset(2, 0).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction. _
                    VLookup(Target, Sheets("Sheet2").Range("$E$3:$F$6"), 2)
                t.Offset(2, 0).Font.Bold = True

                i = 2
                'I really don't know what the following code is intended to do
                'probably better as a conditional formatting rule
                Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(11, i))
                    If Cells(11, i).Value <= ChildCount Then
                        Cells(12, i).Interior.ColorIndex = 19
                    End If
                i = i + 1
                Loop
            End If
        next t
    End If

safe_exit:
    application.enableevents = true

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think I have worked out the cause of the error. it is because, j does not get defined until another question is answered, so when I run the spreadsheet from scratch it does not know what j is. If you knew how I could work my way around this, it would be great!